# Cambiar el texto del un label con jquery con text() o html() no funciona

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

se que para cambiar el valor de un label vale con html() o text() pero el problema es que no funciona. Me explico:

La funcion del programa es que al hacer doble click en un elemento con la clase ".item" se clone ese elemento y lo añada a un div, que el stock se reste en uno y que el precio y el numero de items se incremente.

Defino $stockLblInicial y $cantStockInicial al cargar la página para comprobar si hay stock y si hay hacer el doble click, si no lo hay pues nada.

Carga de la página:

```
    $(function(){

    $("#citem").val(0); //Ponemos el contador de items a cero cada vez que se refresque la pagina
    $("#cprice").val(0 + " €"); //Ponemos el valor del precio total a cero cada ves que se refresque la pagina 

    var $stockLblInicial = $(".stock", $(this)).text(); //Pillamos la etiqueta del stock 
    var $cantStockInicial = parseInt($stockLblInicial.slice(6)); //Cogemos solo el numero y lo pasamos a int 
    //Hago un slice ya que el label es tal que "Stock 10" y solo quiero el numero 

    //Si hay items en stock 
    if($cantStockInicial > 0){
        $(".item").on("dblclick", dobleClickItems);
    }else{
        return false;
    }
});
```

Dentro de la funcion del dobleClick se define $stockLbl y $cantStock porque mas adelante el valor de esas variables se pisará. En la funcion en si coge esos valores para que en compra() se reste en uno el stock y se le asigne al texto del item clickado. El texto no cambia entonces pilla siempre como que hay 10 items. El problema no está en el contador ya que resta como toca. El problema es directamente no cambia el texto. He probado con text() y con html() y no funciona.

```
    function dobleClickItems(){
    //Variable necesarias para clonar
    const $divCarrito = $("#cart_items"); //Pillamos el contenedor del carrito
    let $idItem = $(this).attr("id"); //Pillamos la id del item seleccionado (devuelve un string)
    let $clonedItem = $(this).clone(); //Clonamos el item 

    var $stockLbl = $(".stock", $(this)).text(); //Pillamos la etiqueta del stock 
    var $cantStock = parseInt($stockLbl.slice(6)); //Cogemos solo el numero y lo pasamos a int 

    let $precioLabel = $(".price", $(this)).text(); //Pillamos el precio del producto clickado
    let $precio = parseInt($precioLabel.slice(0, 4)); //Cogemos el numero y lo pasamos a int

    let $numItems = $("#citem").val(); //Pillamos el valor del input de la cantidad de elementos 
    parseInt($numItems); //Pasamos el valor a int para poder hacer operaciones

    //Pillamos el valor del input del precio total y lo pasamos a int tambien 
    let $precioTotal = parseInt($("#cprice").val().slice(0, 4));

    compra($cantStock, $numItems, $precioTotal, $precio);
    cloneItem($idItem, $clonedItem, $divCarrito);

    if($cantStock == 0){ //Si no quedan items le añadimos la clase "agotado" al item 
        $(".stock", $(this)).addClass("agotado");
    }
}
```

Aquí la funcion compra:

```
    function compra($cantStock, $numItems, $precioTotal, $precio){
    $cantStock--; //Contador para decrementar el valor del stock  
    $(".stock", $(this)).html("Stock " + $cantStock); //Reducimos en uno el numero de stock

    console.log("Cantidad en stock " + $cantStock);

    $numItems++; //Incrementamos el numero de items comprados
    $("#citem").val($numItems); //Aumentamos el numero de compras

    console.log($numItems);

    $precioTotal += $precio; //Al precio del input le vamos sumando el precio de todas la compras 
    $("#cprice").val($precioTotal + " €");
}
```

La consola no lanza ningún problema, es solo que el label no lo cambia y no sé por qué puede ser. Si alguien me pudiese ayudar estaria muy agradecido.

El html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Carro de la compra con jQuery</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" title="normal" href="css/carro.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
 <!-- CDN JQuery de Google -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" 
   type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="scripts/carro.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="item_container">
  <div class="item" id="i1">
   <img src="img/camiseta1.jpg" alt="descripción i1"/>
   <label class="title">Camiseta 1</label>
   <label class="price">20 €</label>
   <label class="stock">Stock 10</label>
  </div>
  <div class="item" id="i2">
   <img src="img/reloj2.jpg" alt="descripción i2"/>
   <label class="title">Reloj 2</label>
   <label class="price">24 €</label>
   <label class="stock">Stock 10</label>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
 </div>
 <div id="cart_container">
  <div id="cart_title">
   <span>Carrito</span>
   <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="cart_toolbar">
   <div id="cart_items" class="back"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="navigate">
   <div id="nav_left">
    <button id="btn_comprar" title="Confirma la compra de los artículos">Comprar</button>
    <button id="btn_prev" title="Desplaza el carrito hacia la izquierda">&lt;</button>
    <button id="btn_next" title="Desplaza el carrito hacia la derecha">&gt;</button>
    <button id="btn_clear" title="Vacia el carrito">Vaciar</button>
   </div>
   <div id="nav_right">
    <span class="sptext">
     <label>Compras </label><input id="citem" value="0" readonly title="Número de productos comprados"/>
    </span>
    <span class="sptext">
     <label>Precio </label><input id="cprice" value="0 €" readonly  title="Precio total de los productos comprados"/>
    </span>
   </div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

PD: Si hiciese falta el html edito la pregunta y lo añado también.

EDIT: El error concretamente es que intento editar el label con clase "stock" dentro del div con clase "item" pero no lo hace. Esto concretamente lo hago aquí: `$(".stock", $(this)).html("Stock " + $cantStock);` 
Es la segunda linea de la funcion compra(). 
Espero que esto lo aclare un poco más.

EDIT 2: Quiero modificar el label del elemento al que clicko dos veces es por eso por lo que está la variable $this cuando defino $stockLbl. Lo que quiero es cambiar el contenido de ese label y accedo a el mediante su clase ".stock". Concretamente quiero que al hacer doble click el numero del label se reduzca en uno. Por eso tengo una variable $cantStock que uso como contador y que está inicializada al hacer un split del contenido del label hasta quedarme solo con el numero.

Igual viendo el layout como es se entiende un poco mejor: 
[image: Layout de la app]

Cuando haces doble click en uno de los contenedores donde está el producto el numero del stock se debería reducir en 1.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Creo que convendría que pongas el HTML   (sólo la parte que concierne al problema). Y también sería bueno que explicas claramente dónde falla el código. Tal y como está planteada la pregunta es muy complicado saber dónde está el problema, hay que analizar todo tu código tratando de adivinar lo que hace. Si puedes di, *el problema está aquí en esta parte, lo que pasa es esto y este es el HTML*.

Comment: De acuerdo gracias. Ya he añadido el html y he explicado un poco más el error que tengo. Aunque recalco que la consola no me lanza ningún error de ejecución es simplemente que no realiza la función que debería.

Comment: Estoy tratando de entender el problema, pero entre tantas explicaciones y tanto código me pierdo. Hablas de un label con la clase stock, en el HTML hay dos label que tienen esa clase, este: `<label class="stock">Stock 10</label>` y también este: `<label class="stock">Stock 10</label>`. ¿quieres cambiar algo en esos dos label? ¿o en uno de ellos? ¿en cual?  ¿en qué momento debe ocurrir el cambio? Si no explicas al principio dónde está el problema, llamando cada cosa por su nombre es muy difícil entender. Explica primero y luego pones el código: ...

Comment: ...Algo así: *Tengo problemas con este label, `<label class="stock">Stock 10</label>`, al presionar en el botón que se llama tal, quiero hacer tal cosa con ese label, etc*.

Comment: He intentado aclararlo más y he añadido una imagen del layout que creo que ayudará para entender el funcionamiento de la app.

Comment: No quiero desanimarte, pero tu código es algo confuso. Estoy intentando reproducir el problema basándome solamente en el aspecto de reducir el valor del label cada vez que se haga doble click en cualquier elemento de la clase `item`. El primer problema con el que me encuentro es el siguiente: **¿dónde guardas el valor numérico de la cantidad que hay en stock por cada producto?**

Comment: Lo guardo en $cantStock. Lo que hago para conseguir el valor numerico de es hacer un slice del contenido del label para así quedarme solo con el numero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te propongo una solución basada en el uso de los [atributos `data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).  No me parece correcto un código en el que almacenes valores que son necesarios para cálculos junto con palabras, como es el caso de `Stock`. Con los atributos `data-*` puedes almacenar en cada `div` elementos como la cantidad en stock o el precio como números y usar esos valores para cálculos futuros. Y cosas más profesionales serían más fáciles de implementar, como el hecho de deshabilitar los elementos cuando el stock llegue a `0`.

En este fragmento, se escuchan los doble clicks del `div` y en cada doble click se reduce en uno el stock.

Ten en cuenta que este código te será muy útil también si quieres trabajar con el precio por ejemplo. O si quieres pasar el elemento clickeado a otra parte, como a un carrito de compras o algo parecido. Y te evitará tener que estar limpiando el contenido del label para obtener solamente el valor numérico.

Yo he usado código Javascript puro. Puedes usar jQuery si quieres, pero se recomienda evitar el uso de librerías externas cuando puedes hacerlo con JS puro (el código es más rápido).

Espero te sea de utilidad. Puedes probar su funcionamiento...

```js
/*Asignamos un listener a todos los elementos de la clase item*/
var elementsArray = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
elementsArray.forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener("dblclick", dobleClick, false);
});
/*Esta es la función definida en el listener*/
function dobleClick() {
  /*Con dataset.[nombre] obtenemos el valor que hay en ese atributo*/
  var stockReduced = this.dataset.stock - 1;
  /*Actualizamos el atributo a [valor-1]*/ 
  this.dataset.stock= stockReduced;
  /*Referencia al label stock*/
  var lblStock = this.getElementsByTagName('label')[2];
  /*Actualizamos el valor numérico de forma dinámica*/
  lblStock.textContent = `Stock ${stockReduced}`;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="item_container">
  <div class="item" id="i1" data-stock="10" data-price="20">
    <img src="img/camiseta1.jpg" alt="descripción i1" />
    <label class="title">Camiseta 1</label>
    <label class="price">20 €</label>
    <label class="stock">Stock 10</label>
  </div>
  <div class="item" id="i2" data-stock="10" data-price="24">

    <img src="img/reloj2.jpg" alt="descripción i2" />
    <label class="title">Reloj 2</label>
    <label class="price">24 €</label>
    <label class="stock">Stock 10</label>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Funciona perfectamente, lo implemento así como me lo explicas. Un saludo!

Comment: @yonvela20 me alegro de que te haya funcionado. Considera marcar como buena la respuesta que más se acerca a la solución de tu problema, para que el caso no quede abierto. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias! No sabía como funcionaba lo de marcar una respuesta como buena, queda hecho!

Answer (score 1):

La funcionalidad está mal planteada por muchas razones, pero vamos a lo inmediato:

Tienes dos funciones ajenas al evento `$(document).ready({...})` que debieran funcionar según sus parámetros y no acopladas a lo que definas dentro del bloque antes menionado. **Esto es correcto**, no quieres que haya acoplamiento ni pisar variables generales dentro de funciones.

Declaras un listener sobre `$(".stock", $(this))` que alude a tantos items como tengas a la venta. **Eso es correcto**, significa que todos tienen ese comportamiento.

En particular, cuando buscas

```
$(".stock", $(this))
```

Dentro de `$(function() {...})` `this` es el documento. Por lo que se interpreta como:

```
$(".stock", $(document))
```

El listener invoca a un handler `dobleClickItems`. **Eso es correcto**, ya que que este handler de jQuery recibe una referencia al elemento, por lo cual, dentro de `dobleClickItems`, `$(this)` es el item que se ha pinchado.

Aquí viene el problema. Dentro del `dobleClickItems` llamas a `compra`. Pero compra es una función común y corriente. No es un handler de jQuery. Dentro de `compra` `$(this)` **ha perdido la referencia al** `item`, e incluso ha perdido la referencia al  `document`. El intérprete se ve obligado a suponer que es una referencia a `window`, y

```
$(".stock", $(window))
```

No identifica a ningún elemento.

**Solución propuesta**

Primero, tienes N productos. Quieres comprobar si tienen inventario. En caso afirmativo, les das el comportamiento clickeable. Para esto debieras chequear el inventario de cada producto:

```
$(".item").each(function() {
  var inventario = ...;
  if(inventario > 0) {
    ... tienen comportamiento doble click...
  }
});
```

Ahora, para saber si tienen inventario, considerando que el inventario está en un label, no me parece correcto usar el texto del label que, mal que mal, está pensado para ser un texto y no un valor. Dentro del label yo pondría un input de manera que fuese:

```
<label class="stock">Stock 
   <input type="text" readonly value="10">
</label>
```

Y obtener el stock de cada producto usando:

```
$(".item").each(function() {
  var inputInventario = $(this).find('input'); 
  var inventario = parseInt(inputInventario.val(), 10);
  if(inventario > 0) {
     $(this).on("dblclick", dobleClickItems);
  }
});
```

Ahora cada producto es clickeable o no dependiendo de su stock propio, sin importar el producto del lado.

Cuando vas a comprar, dentro de `dobleClickItems` tienes la referencia al item que se ha pinchado, por lo que podrías hacer, de nuevo:

```
function dobleClickItems() {
   var inputInventario = $(this).find('input');
   var inventario = parseInt(inputInventario.val(), 10);

   ... más cosas...   
}
```

Y rebajar el inventario antes de ejecutar la compra. La compra es un acto que interactúa con el carrito y no con el inventario, no le metas responsabilidad sobre un ámbito que le es ajeno:

```
function dobleClickItems() {
       var inputInventario = $(this).find('input');
       var inventario = parseInt(inputInventario.val(), 10);

    inventario--;
    inputInventario.val(inventario);

    compra($numItems, $precioTotal, $precio);       
}
```

Fíjate que quité la referencia a la cantidad de stock en la función compra. Por otro lado, yo también quitaría el cálculo de los items del carrito de la función `dobleClickItems`. En el diseño, lo que se hace con los items no sabe lo que se hace con el carrito. Lo que se hace con el carrito no tiene idea de lo que hiciste con los items. Cada función tiene [una única responsabilidad](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_de_responsabilidad_%C3%BAnica) y entre sí hablan según la [ley de Deméter](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ley_de_Demeter). Mientras menos sepa cada función lo que hace la otra, mejor.

**Solución Estéticamente Elaborada**:

Puede que no quieras que se vea el inventario como una cajita de input.  No hay problema. Podrías usar una propiedad del label (ej `rel`) para almacenar el stock disponible, y poner un seudoelemento **que desplegara la cantidad de stock sin tocar el texto**, sino usando un atributo. Por ejemplo, piensa que defines el stock del producto 1 usando:

```
<div class="item" id="i1">
   <label class="stock" rel="10">Stock </label>
</div>
```

Y en la hoja de estilos `carro.css` le pones un seudoelemento cuyo contenido es el atributo `rel` del label:

```
.item .stock:after {
    content: attr(rel);
    width: 20px;
}
```

Entonces, cuando quisieras conocer el stock disponible usarías:

```
$(".item").each(function() {
  var relInventario = $(this).attr('rel'); 
  var inventario = parseInt(relInventario, 10);
  if(inventario > 0) {
     $(this).on("dblclick", dobleClickItems);
  }
});
```

Y para modificar el inventario:

```
inventario--;
$(this).attr('rel',inventario);
```

Verás que el seudoelemento cambia acorde a la propiedad, sin que toques el texto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias! Ya veo el porque del error, pero... Qué debería hacer para solucionarlo? Cuando llamo a  $(".stock", $(this)).html("Stock " + $cantStock); en compra() en vez de a $this, a que debería llamar?

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! Le pego un ojo para entenderlo bien y demás pero me funciona a la perfección! Un saludo!